# is there a jquery plugin to show sign-up/registration progress?

Tags: jquery

I'm looking for a quick and easy way of showing users position in the sign up page, in a nice way.

you see these things for stuff like basket->checkout->confirm details->payment, often they look a bit like a public transport map o----o----o----o if that makes sense?!

Any plugins to do this without me opening photoshop?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try the [jQuery.jBreadCrumb](http://www.comparenetworks.com/developers/jqueryplugins/jbreadcrumb.html) plugin

Comment: thanks that's interesting, pretty irritating animation / poor user experience though don't you think!

Comment: sure, you may want to use the "normal" behaviour, without any animation at all